# google translate command? (python)

Tags: python, discord.py

So I want to make a command for my discord bot that translates stuff. I'm using repl.it and the googletrans pip install code won't work for some reason. I also tried doing `pip install googletrans==3.1.0a0` in the shell, but it won't work either. Is there currently a code for google translate that works in python or an updated one that works for repl.it??

here's my current code (when i try the command, it doesn't respond):

````
@client.command(aliases=['tr'])
async def translate(ctx, lang_to, *args):
  lang_to = lang_to.lower()
  if lang_to not in googletrans.LANGUAGES and lang_to not in googletrans.LANGCODES:
    raise commands.BadArgument("Invalid language detected. Make sure to check if it is spelled correctly and that it is a real language.")

  text = ' '.join(args)
  translator = googletrans.Translator()
  text_translated = translator.translate(text, dest=lang_to).text
  await ctx.send(text_translated)```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (for example, include enough "framing" code to get a bot started), and describe the problem more clearly. What do you mean by "doesn't respond"? Does the code work stand-alone (outside a discord bot)?

Answer (score 0):

Hey try to Install google translator version 4.0.0rc1!
`pip install googletrans==4.0.0rc1`

My code:

```
@bot.command() 
async def trans(ctx, lang, *, args):
  t= Translator()
  a= t.translate(args, dest=lang)
  tembed= discord.Embed(title=f'Translating Language....', description=f'Successfully translated the text below :point_down:  \n \n**{a.text}**', color=discord.Colour.random())
  await ctx.send(embed=tembed)
  print(googletrans.LANGUAGES)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).